# Why Thread not releasing lock when reference has changed

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class UThread implements Runnable {

    Object o;

    UThread(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (o) {
            System.out.println("inside before change" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception er) {
            }
            o = new Object();
            System.out.println("inside after change" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception er) {
            }

        }
        System.out.println("outside " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    }


}


public class main {
    public static void main(String str[]) {

        Object o = new Object();
        UThread uThread = new UThread(o);
        Thread th = new Thread(uThread);

        UThread uThread2 = new UThread(o);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(uThread2);

        th.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception er) {
        }
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

When we execute the code it print

inside before changeThread-0
inside after changeThread-0
outside Thread-0
inside before changeThread-1
inside after changeThread-1
outside Thread-1

So why second thread not taken the lock on `o` when I change the object.

Comment: Locking on a non-final reference is a bad idea.

Comment: @AndyTurner indeed it's a bad idea; unfortunately, Sun themselves didn't make the `protected Object lock;` in Writer.java final, so whenever I subclass Writer I get a warning from my static analysis tools.

Answer (score 4):

Assigning a reference does nothing to the underlying object. All it does is copy the reference value without touching or altering the object itself.  It doesn't for example, release a lock nor should it.

e.g.

```
Object o2 = o;
synchronized(o) {
    o = new Object();
    // o2 is still locked
}
// o2 is not locked
```

Answer (score 2):

The second thread has requested a lock for the original object referenced by the `o` variable (the one created in your main method and passed to the constructor of the two `UThread` instances).

Changing the value of `o` inside the synchronized block of the first thread doesn't change the fact that this thread already locked the original object referenced by `o`, which the second thread is also waiting to lock.